# How to find the rel attribute jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a bunch of elements that contain the rel attribute.

I'm trying to use this to loop through the elements to get the value of each.

```
$('area').find('rel').each(function(index){
    alert(index);
});
```

However it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `find` is supposed to be a selector. To actually pull out the element values, you want something like:

```
$('[rel]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('[rel]')` would find all nodes with the rel attribute in document.

`$('div').find('[rel]')` would find all nodes  with the rel attribute in under any div.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind figured it out.

```
$('area[rel]').each(function(index){
    alert(index);
});
```